# DocuSign authorization code grant - multi users in Docusign Account

Tags: authentication, token, docusignapi

I'm using Authorization Code Grant to authenticate from my cloud app to DocuSign. I followed the excellent directions provided by DocuSign. When I authenticate the user I get the DocuSign Login screen and consent dialog. If I then authenticate again somehow DocuSign decides the user hasn't changed and doesn't pop up the login and consent dialog. Usually this is acceptable because it is indeed the same user.

However, if I logout of my application and then (before closing browser) relog in to my application as a **different** user then I am expecting that when I request to authenticate to DocuSign that the login and consent will come up. That isn't happening and DocuSign returns user information for the original user.

What mechanism is DocuSign using to determine that the user hasn't changed? Is it browser cache? More importantly is there a way I can disable that when I am starting the authorization code grant so that I can authenticate the second user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add query parameter &prompt=login in your initial url. This will show login page everytime.